# Qual a diferença entre uma função documentada e uma apenas com lista de argumentos?

Tags: php, mysql

Estava dando uma lida pela documentação do PHP e me deparei com essa nota quando estava passando pela função `str_getcsv`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E fiquei com a dúvida de qual seria a diferença que isso implica, alguém disposto a explicar ou dizer onde seria a melhor fonte para buscar essa informação?

Comment: As vezes a versão em português da ajuda não está completa. Verifique a [versão em inglês da ajuda](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diferença é que uma função documentada tem todas as informações necessárias para você utilizar a mesma. Como por exemplo: argumentos necessários, o que a função retorna, exemplos de como utilizar a função, possíveis erros e etc. E a lista de argumentos só tem os argumentos necessários para utilizar na função.